# openapi stripe payload definition for events

Tags: openapi

Hi I am trying to find a way to define this structure in openapi

```json
{
  "id": "evt_1M42aUGgA02srhGVcjgIsoS2",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": null,
  "created": 1668432034,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "price_1M42aUJX9HHJ5bycQphyzwec",
      "object": "plan",
      "active": true,
      "aggregate_usage": null,
      "amount": 2000,
      "amount_decimal": "2000",
      "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
      "created": 1668432034,
      "currency": "pln",
      "interval": "month",
      "interval_count": 1,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "nickname": null,
      "product": "prod_Mm9YCJ0pVG7qCh",
      "tiers_mode": null,
      "transform_usage": null,
      "trial_period_days": null,
      "usage_type": "licensed"
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 0,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "plan.created"
}
```

where the `data.object` is dynamic and depends on event trigger

```json
"object": {
      "id": "price_1M42aUJX9HHJ5bycQphyzwec",
      "object": "plan",
      "active": true,
      "aggregate_usage": null,
      "amount": 2000,
      "amount_decimal": "2000",
      "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
      "created": 1668432034,
      "currency": "pln",
      "interval": "month",
      "interval_count": 1,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "nickname": null,
      "product": "prod_Mm9YCJ0pVG7qCh",
      "tiers_mode": null,
      "transform_usage": null,
      "trial_period_days": null,
      "usage_type": "licensed"
    }
```

the current definition I am using in openapi is:

```yaml
StripeEvent:
      properties:
        api_version:
          type: string
        object:
          type: string
        account:
          type: string
        created:
          type: integer
        data: 
          type: object 
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/StripeEventObject'
        id:
          type: string
        livemode: 
          type: boolean
        pending_webhooks:
          type: integer
        request:
          type: object
          properties:
            id: 
              type: string
            idempotency_key:
              type: string
        type:
          type: string
```

and the nested object

```yaml
StripeEventObject:
      properties:
        object: 
          type: object
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/StripeEventNestedObject'
    StripeEventNestedObject:
      additionalProperties:
        type: object
```

the problem is that the embedded `data.object` when I am receiving the payload is empty, so my question is .. if there is a way to define this part dynamically ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `StripeEventObject` schema to:

```yaml
    StripeEventObject:
      type: object
      properties:
        object: 
          type: object   # Free-form object
```

`type: object` alone without `properties`/`additionalProperties` means it's a free-form/dynamic object with arbitrary properties.

You don't need `additionalProperties: {type: ...}` in the nested schema, it's used to define maps/dictionaries.